# I want to send the details of this form as an email,

Tags: php, forms, html.dropdownlistfor

> The mailing address depends on the city selected from the dropdown
>   list.I have troubles with the php code.please help me.

```
<form action="">
        <ul>
            <li><input name="name" type="text" placeholder="type name" /></li>
            <li><input name="email" type="email"  placeholder="type email"/></li>
            <li><input name="num" type="number" placeholder="type contact number" /></li>
           <div class="dropdown">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg dropdown-toggle btn-block" data-toggle="dropdown" id="city">
     Select City
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Sydney</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Brisbane</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Melbourne</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Canberra</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Darwin</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Perth</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
            <li><input name="submit" type="submit" /></li>
        </ul>

    </form>
```

> there is my php try

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 switch($_POST['city']) {
  case 'Sydney': $to = 'to1@gmail.com'; break;
  case 'Brisbane': $to = 'to2@hotmail.com'; break;
 }
}
```

Comment: Plz give the output of your code.

Comment: thats a unordered list not a select/option. Unless you have some javascript that you didn't include. Try `var_dump($_POST)` to see what is being sent

Answer (score 0):

please see below. I have tried and tested code below and it works. try it out.

```
<html>
    <head>
            <title>Sending Email</title>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {

                    $("#Send").click(function(){
                        var Name=$('#Name').val();
                        var Email=$('#Email').val();
                        var Num=$('#Num').val();
                        var City= $("#City option:selected").text();

                        $.post('sendmail.php',{Name:Name,Email:Email,Num:Num, City:City},function(data){

                    alert(data);

                    });



                    });


                    });                 
            </script>
    </head>

    <body>
            <form onsubmit="return false;" id="UserReg">

             <ul>
                        <li>Name:<input id="Name"  type="text" placeholder="type name" /></li>
                        <li>Email:<input id="Email" type="email"  placeholder="type email"/></li>
                        <li>Number:<input id="Num" type="text" placeholder="type contact number" /></li>
                        <li>City:<select id="City">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="Sydney">Sydney</option>
                        <option value="Brisbane">Brisbane</option>
                        <option value="Melbourne">Melbourne</option>
                        <option value="Canberra">Canberra</option>
                        <option value="Darwin">Darwin</option>
                        <option value="Perth">Perth</option>

                        </select>


            </ul>           



            <input type="submit" value="Send" id="Send"/>

            </form>
    </body>
<html>

<?php
    if($_POST)
    {
        $Name=$_POST["Name"];
        $Email=$_POST["Email"];
        $Num=$_POST["Num"];
        $City=$_POST["City"];
        $To;

    switch($City) {
      case 'Sydney': $To = 'to1@gmail.com'; break;
      case 'Brisbane': $To = 'to2@hotmail.com'; break;
                        }

        $Message="Name is".$Name." Email is:".$Email." Num is:".$Num;

    $Send=mail($To,"Details of".$Name,$Message) 
    if($Send)
    {
        echo "Email Sent to".$City;
        exit();
    }
    else
    {

    echo "Error encountered";
    exit();

    }


    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

because you are not submitting any input regarding city. use an html input element for city to get it submitted to be available with $_POST
here are the list of input elements:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Answer (score -2):

on submitting page will redirect to secondpage.php and from the second page mail will go as follows

and 
//secondpage.php

$body=$_POST['name'];
mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)